# How to load a ListView with a multiple array

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to load my ListView from the following array

```
static final String[][] Bookings = new String[][] {{"WC11", "John Smith"},{"WX11", "Terry Jones"}};
```

I'm try to use the following code but Eclipse wont accept it.

```
ListView bkgList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bkg_list);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, Bookings));
```

It says 'the constructor ArrayAdapter(ListVActivity, int, String[][]) is undefined'. How can I load my array into my ListView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArrayAdapter is for a 1-d Array and the constructor expects something like `String[] bookings`.

You can do something like this. Keep in mind you would need to override toString() of Booking because that is what is displayed in the TextView.

```
class Booking {
    String type;
    String name;
    public Booking(String type, String name) {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

Booking[] Bookings = new Booking[2];
Bookings[0] = new Booking("WC11", "John Smith");
Bookings[1] = new Booking("WX11", "Terry Jones");

ListView bkgList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bkg_list);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Booking>(this, R.layout.list_item, Bookings));
```

If you want to keep the 2-d array you can extend [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) to make a custom BookingsAdapter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added the code and I get two errors 'The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(ListVActivity, int, Booking[]) is undefined' and 'The method setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>) is undefined for the type ListVActivity'. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: @user616076 I updated the code. Needed to change the generic parameter from String to Booking

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than a single `TextView` per row of your `ListView` you may want to consider subclassing `BaseAdapter` rather than using `ArrayAdapter`.

For an example of how to do this, see [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html)