# Error in Java File (Android)

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, cursor

Eclipse gives me error on this line 
ArrayAdapter myAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,myArray);

Here is the code :

```
package com.dbapp.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {  

int i,j;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        String[][] myArray=new String[10][10];
        ListView myListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);



        CRUD crud=new CRUD(this);
        crud.openDb();

        Cursor cursor= crud.readDbRows();
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        i=j=0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
        myArray[i][0]=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("column1"));
        myArray[i][1]=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("column2"));
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,myArray);
        myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

}
```

This is not main activity, it is just Another activity.

Comment: what error you getting??

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that ArrayAdapter takes 1D array as arguments , not a 2D.

So, I changed the code to 1D array and found the answer.

I had to change the string array to\

```
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and add elements using the following line :

```
myArray.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
```

Heres the java code

```
package com.example.databasedemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.databasedemo.CRUD;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);


    ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView listv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.dblist);

    CRUD crud=new CRUD(this);
    crud.openDb();
    Cursor cursor= crud.readDbRows();
    cursor.moveToFirst();


    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        myArray.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));

    }



    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myArray);
    listv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    crud.closeDb();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdaptater is for a one dimension array.

See a similar problem here  [How to load a ListView with a multiple array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157883/how-to-load-a-listview-with-a-multiple-array)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which API you are onto, but from API level 17 you may do something like that:

```
   myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, myArray){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                TwoLineListItem row;            
                if(convertView == null){
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row = (TwoLineListItem)inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null);                    
                }else{
                    row = (TwoLineListItem)convertView;
                }
                BasicNameValuePair data = list.get(position);
                row.getText1().setText(myArray[position][0]);
                row.getText2().setText(myArray[position][1]);

                return row;
            }
        };
    myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: @AjZ Yeah, that is just a suggestion, since you did not specify which API level you are using. Regarding your error - post the error so we can understand what you are doing wrong

Comment: array index out of bounds. (as seen in logcat).

Comment: @AjZ can you post your `crud.readDbRows()` method implementation?

Comment: @AjZ also Cursor.moveToFirst() returns false if the Cursor is empty. The returned Cursor from the query() call will never be null but it might be empty. You are never checking if the cursor is empty.

Comment: Well, it seems that ArrayAdapter takes 1D array as arguments , not a 2D.

So, I changed the code to 1D array but still no success, so I'm using a different approach to get to this tutorial, anyways thanks for the help guys